# What is the best way for showing a grid of customer logos?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm speaking about the frequent "our customers" section, usually a grid of customer logos that link to their respective websites/success case posts. The site owner should be able to add or remove these at ease.

Right now, the best approach I could came up with is adding a custom image size to the theme  and include the page as a regular page with all the logos in the content like `<div id="customers"><a href="http://site.com">Customer</a></div>`.

I Googled thinking this should be a popular topic, but not really :P.

Comment: Customers from where exactly?

Comment: @BradDalton just customers from the company that owns of the site.

Comment: I mean where are you pulling them from? Are they users added in WordPress?

Comment: @BradDalton No, just hand picked logos that the site owner chose as significant to show him off. :)

Comment: You could use the native WordPress gallery or an archive.php with CSS to display the featured images in a grid.

Answer (score 2):

> Grid of customer logos that link to their respective websites/success case posts. The site owner should be able to add or remove these at ease.

Well I think the easiest way would to create a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) called "Customer Logos". After that you could handle content and images multiple ways:

**More Precise Control but More Work**

[Create an image size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) which will represent each logo. Whenever [registering your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) you'll want to make sure that it supports `thumbnail` so that the Site Owner can upload a "Featured Image" which would be the Customer Logo. You could then create a [Metabox](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) to store your link which would be stored as postmeta. This will make sure that the user can only add a title, image, and link and when creating your grid you can make sure everything is consistent.

**Easier but Less Control**

Instead of the above, whenever you [registering your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) you can just have it support `title, editor` of which the Site Owner can just upload the image to the post type and link it directly. The problem with this method is it gives the Site Owner more room to mess up any layout you decide to go with.

**Finally**

You'll have to create a [Post Type Archive](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/) to display your posts and some HTML / CSS to put them into a loop. Hopefully that gives you a better idea on where to start and what to do but you'll have to do some coding.

Comment: This is a good idea which i use on my own site and display the featured images for each single CPT in a grid on the archive page which you can do using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the logos as a gallery into the post content and write the gallery output on your own.

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'your_gallery_output_function', 10, 2 );

function your_gallery_output_function( $output, $attr ) {
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => $orderby, 
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'number_of_posts' => -1
    );

    // get images
    $images = get_posts( $args );

    // if no images are found
    if ( empty( $images ) )
        return;

    // add a wrapper around all images
    $output = '<div class="your-gallery-wrapper">';

    // loop through the images
    foreach ( $images as $an_image ) {
        // .. do something with all the logos here
        // and add them to $output...
    }
    // close wrapper
    $output.= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
```